# Extract part of XML file

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, sax

I have a big XML file w/ repeating parts in it. How can i extract these parts 'as is' one-by-one in Java? As i said file is huge so i can't load it into memory.

What technology/library should i use to iterate through the file and in each iteration extract a single part?

Here is example of what i need. 
Origin file content (snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<Details>
 <Detail>
  <CSDate>2017-01-11</CSD> 
  <CN>Smth</CN> 
  <IN>Some number</IN>   
 </Detail>
 <Detail>
  <CSDate>2017-02-11</CSD> 
  <CN>Smth1</CN> 
  <IN>Some number 1</IN>   
 </Detail>
 <Detail>
  <CSDate>2017-03-11</CSD> 
  <CN>Smth 2</CN> 
  <IN>Some number 2</IN>   
 </Detail>
</Details>
```

And in result i need to get such snippet 'as-is' w/ all the tags & attributes if any:

```
<Detail>
  <CSDate>2017-03-11</CSD> 
  <CN>Smth 2</CN> 
  <IN>Some number 2</IN>   
 </Detail>
```

Thanks in advance for any assist

Comment: when you say you can't load it into memory, you meant  DOM will throw out of mem exception?

Comment: I mean that loading to memory is not an option at all

Comment: I think you just have to use streaming xml parsers to do  a lot parsing and serialization... no getting around this...

Comment: Thanx. it seems the only way here..

Comment: It seems that most easy solution here is merely extract lines from file one-by-one and keep them in a StringBuffer. Of course it is fine when XML file is well-formed